# Reverse engeneering a camera

Tags: embedded

today i just want to know if it is possible to reverse-engineer a camera, for example change it so that three photos are taken if i take a photo, or several photos with differing depths, stuff like that.

i know my way around assembler, and i think most cameras use an assembler dialect that is common. But my question is: how do i hook into the camera? how would you do this?

cheers

Comment: Better off at http://Photo.StackExchange.com/

Comment: sorry didnt know about photo.stackexchange :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

This project focus on reverse engineering of Canon cameras: http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK